# BULK Collect into misleading error messages for ORA-00913 & ORA-00947

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
desc book_data;

Name       Null Type         
---------- ---- ------------ 
BOOK_NAME       VARCHAR2(50) 
BOOK_PRICE      NUMBER       
BOOK_SSN        VARCHAR2(50) 



DECLARE
  TYPE book_rec is record(
    book_name  varchar2(50),
    book_price number,
    book_ssn   varchar2(50)
    );
  type book_tbl_type is table of book_rec;
  book_tbl1 book_tbl_type := book_tbl_type();
BEGIN

  SELECT BOOK_NAME, BOOK_PRICE/*,book_ssn,1*/ BULK COLLECT INTO book_tbl1 FROM book_data;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(book_tbl1(1).book_name);
END;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 75:
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**Question : Here we are inserting two columns into three column collection table Then We Should have got "ORA-00947: not enough values" error.But We are getting "ORA-00913: too many values". Why ?**

```
DECLARE
  TYPE book_rec is record(
    book_name  varchar2(50),
    book_price number,
    book_ssn   varchar2(50)
    );
  type book_tbl_type is table of book_rec;
  book_tbl1 book_tbl_type := book_tbl_type();
BEGIN

  SELECT BOOK_NAME, BOOK_PRICE,book_ssn,1 BULK COLLECT INTO book_tbl1 FROM book_data;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(book_tbl1(1).book_name);
END;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 71:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**Question : Here we are inserting four columns into three column collection table . Then We Sould have got "ORA-00913: too many values" error .
               But We are getting "ORA-00947: not enough values". Why ?**

Answer (score 0):

*ORA-00913 too many values
Cause: The SQL statement requires two sets of values equal in number. This error occurs when the second set contains more items than the first set. For example, the subquery in a WHERE or HAVING clause may return too many columns, or a VALUES or SELECT clause may return more columns than are listed in the INSERT.
Action: Check the number of items in each set and change the SQL statement to make them equal.*

In case of BULK COLLECT it seems that the error message refers to the number of columns in collection table, not to the number of selected columns..

To avoid similar problems you can use %ROWTYPE, something like that:

```
DECLARE
  type book_tbl_type is table of book_data%ROWTYPE;
  book_tbl1 book_tbl_type := book_tbl_type();
BEGIN
  SELECT b.* BULK COLLECT INTO book_tbl1 FROM book_data b;
END;
/
```